# Commenting in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, comments

I'm trying to comment/uncomment a block of code using the shortcut "Ctrl+C" and "Ctrl+K", but it's not working. Nothing happens.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have it backwards, its CTRL+K, CTRL+C to comment, CTRL+K, CTRL+U to uncomment.

Here is a list of [Visual Studio Shorcuts](http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx) (The article doesn't specify which version, but I don't believe they have changed)

Comment: If there's a comma, that means "and", not "or"?

Comment: @mathee: + means "press both", comma means "and then..". So press Ctrl and K simultaniously, then press both Ctrl and C (you can keep Ctrl pressed or release it in between, that doesn't matter)

Answer (score 0):

try this

ctrl -k + c : command out the selected code

ctrl -k + u : uncommand out the selected code

Answer (score 0):

**CTRL + "k" + "c"** and **CTRL + "k" + "u"**: These two are for commenting selected text (the "c" options) and uncommenting selected text (the "u" option).

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked your settings?
Tools >> Options >> Keyboard (make sure "Show all settings" is checked) and search for Edit.CommentSelection...